# How can I view/find the file path of currently opened files in Light Table?

Tags: ide

I have a project in [Light Table](http://www.lighttable.com/) with files in different directories that have the same name:

- `project/dir1/file.txt`
- `project/dir2/file.txt`

When I open both files, all I see are two tabs both labelled `file.txt`.  How can I easily distinguish between the two?

In other words, how can I view/find the file path of currently opened files?

Answer (score 0):

I had an old version of Light Table.  The latest version provides a tooltip showing the file directory when you hover over the tab.